# what is the reason of this error?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

in my code I want to use from `get_title()` method of my `Album` class but if I include "album.h" in customer.cpp, it gives me this error:

```
error C2036: 'Song *' : unknown size
```

but now I have this errors:

```
error C2227: left of '->get_title' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
error C2027: use of undefined type 'Album'
IntelliSense: pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed
```

how can I access to methods of my `Album` class?

customer.cpp :

```
#include "customer.h"

void Customer::print_tmpPurchase()
{
    if (tmpPurchase.get_albums().size() != 0)
    {
        cout << "Albums Of Your Basket: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < tmpPurchase.get_albums().size(); i++)
        {
            cout << "\t" << i + 1 << "." << tmpPurchase.get_albums()[i]->get_title() << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

purchase.h :

```
#ifndef PURCH_H
#define PURCH_H

class Song;
class Album;

class Purchase{
public:
    vector <Song*> get_songs() { return songs; }
    vector <Album*> get_albums() { return albums; }
private:
    vector <Song*> songs;
    vector <Album*> albums;
};

#endif
```

album.h :

```
#ifndef ALBUM_H
#define ALBUM_H

class Song;

class Album{
public:
    string get_title() { return title; }
private:
    string title;
    vector <Song> songs;
};
#endif
```

customer.h :

```
#ifndef CUST_H
#define CUST_H

class Purchase;

class Customer{
public:
    void print_tmpPurchase();
private:
    Purchase tmpPurchase;
};

#endif
```

song.h :

```
#ifndef SONG_H
#define SONG_H

class Album;

class Song{
// . . .

private:
    Album* album;
};

#endif
```

Comment: please share customer.h code

Comment: @GaneshKamath No please. Sharing more code dosn't make this question any better (even worse I'd suspect).

Comment: but i can atleast compile and check if something can be improved for this chap

Comment: @GaneshKamath _"but i can atleast compile and check ..."_ It's usually not worth doing so. The OP's in charge 1st to provide a [**minimal** example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can use to reproduce this error, and to explain what's unclear for them.

Comment: @GaneshKamath /OT If you mean to respond to me specifically please put a `@πάντα ῥεῖ` in your message (typing `@` and select from the proposals is usually sufficient, if your keyboard doesn't provide grrek characters), otherwise I'm not getting pinged, that a response for my comments was made.

Comment: @GaneshKamath I edited my code and try to make it readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the class *definitions* are not visible to the compiler when you try to access members of an instance. Although you have provided forward declarations for the classes this is not enough. In the .cpp and .h files that access members of these classes or require their sizes you need to include *all* appropriate headers so that their *definitions* are visible at the point of use. In this case however your `Album` class appears to require the definition of `Song` rather than just a forward declaration.

In `Album.h` add

```
#include "Song.h"
```

In `customer.cpp` add

```
#include "Album.h'
```

and so on...

Comment: thank you so much. I only include album.h in customer.cpp and it works.